# The change of parameter of a regular curve is a diffeomorphism, and preserves the length

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $C$ be a regular curve and let $\alpha:I\subset\mathbb{R}\to C$, $\beta:J\subset\mathbb{R}\to C$ be two parametrizations of $C$ in a neighborhood of $p\in\alpha(I)\cap\beta(I)=W$. Let

$$h=\alpha^{-1}\circ\beta:\beta^{-1}(W)\to\alpha^{-1}(W)$$

be the change of parameters. Prove that

> **a.** $h$ is a diffeomorphism.
>
> **b.** The absolute value of the arc length of $C$ in $W$ does not depend on which parametrization is chose to define it, that is,

$$\left|\int_{t_0}^{t}|\alpha'(t)|\text{d}t\right|=\left|\int_{t_0}^{\tau}|\beta'(\tau)|\text{d}\tau\right|, \ \ \ \ t=h(\tau), t\in I,\tau\in J.$$

#### Progress

Maybe I can show that $h=a^{-1}\circ b : b^{-1}(W)\to a^{-1}(W)$  is a homeomorphism. But I have no idea how can I show this is in fact a diffeomorphism.

Comment: I can't solve that.Help please.May be I can show that h=a−1 b:b−1(W)−−−−>a−1(W) is a homeomorphism.But I have no idea how can I show this is a diffeomorphism realy.Thanks.

Comment: We just need to compute that the derivative of that function is never zero. Being continuous it has a constant sign. Therefore $\alpha^{-1}\circ\beta$ is monotone from an interval onto another. Well, and then do it for the inverse $\beta^{-1}\circ\alpha$.